# Binding Windows Form Combobox to Anonymous Type

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` where string is a path to a file. I want to display the name of the File in a combo box and then use the file name as the value to capture it on `SelectedValueChanged`.

```
  var cmbDatasource = (from moduleReference in moduleReferences
                       select new { FilePath = moduleReference.Key, Filename = new FileInfo(moduleReference.Key).Name }).ToList();
  cmbModules.DataSource = cmbDatasource;
  cmbModules.DisplayMember = "Filename";
  cmbModules.ValueMember = "FilePath";
```

I am then doing this in my `SelectedValueChanged` event

```
private void cmbModules_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
  if (cmb != null)
  {
    var test = cmb.SelectedValue.ToString();
  }
}
```

`test` now becomes the anonymous type as apose to the value member (Path).

> [Using SelectedItem property of ComboBox w/Linq Anonymous Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530482/using-selecteditem-property-of-combobox-w-linq-anonymous-type)

I've looked here but can't see what I am doing differently.

> ### Example

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> moduleReferences = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
moduleReferences.Add("C:\Test.txt", new List<string>());
```

The combobox should display `Test.txt` however when I capture the event I expect to get the `C:\Test.txt` to do a look up in the dictionairy. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: The anonymous type is the problem here, it doesn't override the ToString() method to get the string you want.  So don't use an anonymous type.

Comment: @HansPassant I've come to the same conclusion but your explanation is technically correct. If you'd like to post it as an answer i'll accept it, hopefully will help others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that when you execute

```
var test = cmb.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

You are taking only the value that is selected, not the item itself which will be the same type as moduleReference.Key. If you want to get the entire record you need to do

```
var test = cmb.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: How get Filename value then?

Comment: You can't. Don't use an anonymous type if you want to use it out of the scope. You need to make a class for it.

Comment: @RyanAmies, not true! To get the `Filename` you can do `cmb.GetItemText(cmb.SelectedItem)`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my answer will help someone to find a solution.
With keyword dynamic you can do it this way:

```
var cmbDatasource = (from moduleReference in moduleReferences
                             select (dynamic)new { FilePath = moduleReference.Key, Filename = new FileInfo(moduleReference.Key).Name }).ToList();
        cmbModules.DataSource = cmbDatasource;
        cmbModules.DisplayMember = "Filename";
        cmbModules.ValueMember = "FilePath";
```

and then in selected value changed event handler:

```
private void cmbModules_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var cmb = sender as ComboBox;
  if (cmb != null)
  {
    dynamic item = (dynamic)cmb.SelectedItem;
    string fname = item.Filename;
    string fpath = item.FilePath;
  }
}
```

But it becomes harder to set SelectedItem to a combobox:

```
public void SelectFile(String fname)
{
    foreach (dynamic item in cmbModules.Items)
    {
        if (item.Filename == fname)
        {
            cmbModules.SelectedItem = item;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. you'll need to add a reference to Microsoft.CSharp assembly