# What is the return type of my linq?

Tags: wpf, linq

I have 2 table, and use this query for select some record.

```
   var temp = db.Letters
            .Where(l => !db.SendLetters.Any(s => s.LetterId == l.Id))
            .Select(l => new  { CreatedDate = l.CreatedDate, priority = l.priority, Subject = l.Subject);
  DashboardListView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(temp.ToList());
```

I have a listview and bind it with DashboardListView

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DashboardListView}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"    sort:GridViewSort.AutoSort="True"   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"   >
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridView.Columns >
                               <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Subject}"  Width="170"  sort:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Subject"   />
                               <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CreatedDate}"  Width="110"  sort:GridViewSort.PropertyName="CreatedDate"  />
                               <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding priority}"   Width="80"  sort:GridViewSort.PropertyName="priority" />
                            </GridView.Columns>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

and bind SelectedItem with SelectedItem property. When select a row, i want get items of selecteditem.(Subject, CreatedDate,..)

```
SelectedItem as //type
```

What is the return type of my linq?

Comment: Hover your mouse over the `var` keyword and it ought to tell you. Or, do a `GetType()`.

Comment: Why not debug and see for yourself?

Comment: `IQueryable<{anonymous type}>` looks likely if you fix the missing end brace `}`.

Comment: Trick Question. There is no return type as that wouldn't compile.

Comment: it is a object that return `{ CreatedDate = "1999/04/04 15:14", priority = "orijinal", Subject = "test"}` , how to get items of it?

Comment: Seems duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530482/using-selecteditem-property-of-combobox-w-linq-anonymous-type   or near (ui object differs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LINQ statement returns an IEnumerable of the anonymous type created in

```
.Select(l => new { ... });
```

From the Remarks section in [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx):

> Anonymous types are class types that derive directly from object, and
>   that cannot be cast to any type except object. The compiler provides a
>   name for each anonymous type, although your application cannot access
>   it. From the perspective of the common language runtime, an anonymous
>   type is no different from any other reference type.

Hence in order to use that type somewhere else, you would have to replace it by a regular C# class.

Comment: Thanks a lot, if i replace  it by a regular C# class() ` .Select(l => new  MyClass(){..}` .. when i bind it to listview don't show items..`<GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Subject}"' .. I should changed  GridViewColumn  binding?

Comment: `MyClass` should have the same properties as the anonymous class, and they should all be `public`.